# sql server backups: should i set them to run at the same time?

Tags: sql-server, backup

i have several databases that need to be backed up

should i set the backup times the same? is there a good/bad way to do this?

i am concerned that since they are going to be backing up at the same time they will consume too many resources?? what is the best way to time database back ups?

Comment: How big are they? What version of SQL Server are you running? What hardware are you running on? It all depends on these questions.

Comment: Additionally to Ralph's questions: How many databases are you talking about, are they all on the same server and really what I'm most interested in is what are you using to do the backups?

Comment: im talking about 3 databases, one is 3 gigs they others are like 10mb

Comment: using sql server 2008, i dont know what harder they are writing to, but the system is 10g ram, 64bit windows 7 or something

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With databases that small you can back them up at the same time without issue.

Answer (score 2):

When you say run them at the same time you mean you have some  t-sql task that does the following:

```
backup database master to disk=...
...
backup database Adventureworks to disk=...
```

This isn't exactly 'at the same time'  the commands are synchronous so the backup for master will complete before the backup for adventureworks starts.

If you really want them to run all at the same time, then you can create seperate SQL Agent Jobs to all go off at the same time, but why would you want to do that?